# Both Discord and Slack freeze when receiving a new private message

Tags: freeze, notification, slack

The freeze lasts pretty long, between 30 seconds and a minute. The rest of my system remains perfectly responsive.

With Discord, it seems to only happen when Discord isn't in focus, though I can't confirm that 100%.

With Slack, I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter. Every new private message I get freezes the interface. It's faster to close the program by clicking the icon, clicking "Quit", waiting ~10 seconds for it to give me the "this program is not responding" message, confirming, and then reopen than it is to wait for the interface to wake up again.

It's... pretty strange that both of these programs show such similar behavior, which is why I'm asking about it here in askubuntu instead of each of their respective community forums.

Any idea what could be causing these program-specific freezes? Is there any troubleshooting I can do, or more information I can provide? Please do let me know, and thanks for any help!

- Ubuntu 18.04
- AMD 8320
- GTX 770 (proprietary drivers, 440)
- Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3P
- XFCE 4.12

(I have seen that people have had issues with their desktops freezing, maybe related to the notifications, but this seems to be different. I'm not 100% sure though.)

free -h output:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        7.5G        1.2G        330M        7.0G        7.5G
Swap:          975M        1.0M        974M
```

sudo lshw -C memory output:

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: F1
       date: 08/06/2013
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 4032KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2c
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: Dimm0_PartNum
          vendor: Dimm0_Manufacturer
          physical id: 0
          serial: Dimm0_SerNum
          slot: Node0_Dimm0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
          product: Dimm1_PartNum
          vendor: Dimm1_Manufacturer
          physical id: 1
          serial: Dimm1_SerNum
          slot: Node0_Dimm1
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: F3-1866C10-8G
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: Node0_Dimm2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: F3-1866C10-8G
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: Node0_Dimm3
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
```

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version output:

```
F1
```

snap list output:

```
Name                             Version                     Rev   Tracking       Publisher     Notes
core                             16-2.45.3.1                 9804  latest/stable  canonical✓    core
core18                           20200724                    1885  latest/stable  canonical✓    base
gimp                             2.10.20                     297   latest/edge    snapcrafters  -
gnome-3-26-1604                  3.26.0.20200529             100   latest/stable  canonical✓    -
gnome-3-28-1804                  3.28.0-17-gde3d74c.de3d74c  128   latest/stable  canonical✓    -
gtk-common-themes                0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable  canonical✓    -
gtk2-common-themes               0.1                         13    latest/stable  canonical✓    -
kde-frameworks-5-core18          5.61.0                      32    latest/stable  kde✓          -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18  5.68.0                      4     latest/stable  kde✓          -
kdf                              20.04.0                     61    latest/stable  kde✓          -
spotify                          1.1.26.501.gbe11e53b-15     41    latest/stable  spotify✓      -
vlc                              3.0.11                      1700  latest/stable  videolan✓     -
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Is Discord running from a snap?

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply! I've added the output for each of those commands, and for "snap list", which looks like it doesn't include discord or slack. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for taking some much time here, this has been very helpful. I would have sworn I was on the latest BIOS, but I guess that just goes to show how little credit I should give myself =P It's been flashed and is up and running.

Comment: I've also followed your swapfile instructions. (I had to replace "/swapfile" with my current swapfile location for the first part, but then use the given path "/swapfile" to achieve a 4G swap that persists over reboots. Not sure if that means I did something weird before, but it seems to be set up now as long as that wasn't stupid.)

Running the memtest tonight. Will check back in then.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Getting to it. Thanks for your exceptional patience.

Comment: Hi, switching to 450 gave me resolution issues (it only make something super low available, 640 by something iirc). It is open source vs 440, which is proprietary. Not sure if I should dig any further there, I've just reverted to 440 for now.

Comment: I finally got around to running the memory test overnight. Here are my results:
https://i.imgur.com/DFq2qwo.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/hfroDaV.jpg
So... one warning about high frequency row hammer bit flips? xD
Thanks again for your patience, and any further help

Comment: Did you ever do the BIOS? If so, then I'm stumped. I thought that my answer would solve your problem for sure. Does the `free -h` command properly show 16G memory, and 4G swap?

Comment: Yes thanks, I did flash the new BIOS. free -h shows 4.0G Swap and 15G of memory... I should have 16, is that a bad sign? At this point it might be worth just replacing the memory and seeing if it fixes itself. If there's a chance it's bad, I wonder what other idiosyncracies it could be causing...

Comment: `free -h` showing 15G RAM is not a problem, and since `memtest` passed, your RAM is fine.

Comment: Try updating to 20.04.1 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue with slack with a bad configuration of the notifications daemon in i3

quick test:

```
$ notify-send hi
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
```

Slack would freeze for the duration of the timeout whenever it tried to display a notification (e.g. on private messages)

this article got me to the solution, as I'm not using a DE with built in notifications service:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_notifications

```
Alternatively, making the notification server as a D-Bus service, the notification server can be launched automatically on the first call to it. 

For example, after installing the notification-daemon package, add the following configuration to D-Bus services directory (/usr/share/dbus-1/services or $XDG_DATA_HOME/dbus-1/services):
```

`/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service`

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/notification-daemon-1.0/notification-daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3P

You have BIOS version F1, dated 08/06/2013.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F2g, dated 10/7/2014, and for rev 1.0 motherboards, can be downloaded [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-970A-UD3P-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios).

Note: type 2.x motherboards. [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-970A-UD3P-rev-2x/support#support-dl-bios).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Swap**

Your swap is way too small at 1G. Let's increase it to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Nvidia**

You have Nvidia driver 440.

There's a newer version available, version 450.66, dated 8/18/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]

[image]